# error Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"/"unity-gtk-module" on program run

Tags: unity, package-management, gtk

I just installed Ubuntu 15.10 yesterday and when i run a program I got the following errors:

```
error: libgcrypt.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

1. at first I installed libgcrypt11. but the errors persisted.

then I reinstalled `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gtk2-engines-murrine:i386`
and the error with murrine disapeared.

2. then I ran

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines:i386
   sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-*:i386
   sudo apt-get install libgtkmm-2.4-1c2:i386
   sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module:i386
   ```

and the canberra error disapeared.

And I have this errors left

```
error: libgcrypt.so.11: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
```

3. I tried install and reinstall overlay but no effect yet.
4. I saw a post that says that this could be caused when the packages is not installed but the configs are still in the system. We can see the indication of this situation if rc is displayed in the terminal after doing this command `dpkg -l overlay-scrollbar` [source](http://blog.khmersite.net/2014/12/gtk-message-failed-to-load-module-overlay-scrollbar/).

this is my output though (ii):

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  overlay-scroll 0.2.17.1+15. all          Scrollbar overlay
```

i don't know if the ii is result of the reinstallation

5. regarding unity-gtk-module. i reinstalled `unity-gtk-module-common` and installed `unity-gtk-*` packages

but the error persists.

I would really appreciate some Thoughts on this matter!